# Why is f <$> g <$> x equivalent to (f . g) <$> x although <$> is not right-associative?

Tags: haskell, syntax, infix-notation, applicative, infix-operator

Why is `f <$> g <$> x` equivalent to `(f . g) <$> x` although `<$>` is not right-associative?

(This kind of equivalence is valid in [a popular idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3030675/94687) with plain `$`, but currently `$` is right-associative!)

`<*>` has the same associativity and precedence as `<$>`, but behaves differently!

Example:

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> (show . show) <$> Just 3
Just "\"3\""
Prelude Control.Applicative> show <$> show <$> Just 3
Just "\"3\""
Prelude Control.Applicative> pure show <*> pure show <*> Just 3

<interactive>:12:6:
    Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `a0 -> b0'
    Expected type: (a1 -> String) -> a0 -> b0
      Actual type: (a1 -> String) -> String
    In the first argument of `pure', namely `show'
    In the first argument of `(<*>)', namely `pure show'
    In the first argument of `(<*>)', namely `pure show <*> pure show'
Prelude Control.Applicative> 
Prelude Control.Applicative> :i (<$>)
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    -- Defined in `Data.Functor'
infixl 4 <$>
Prelude Control.Applicative> :i (<*>)
class Functor f => Applicative f where
  ...
  (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  ...
    -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
infixl 4 <*>
Prelude Control.Applicative>
```

From the definition of `<$>`, I would expect `show <$> show <$> Just 3` to fail, too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Why is `f <$> g <$> x` equivalent to `(f . g) <$> x`?

This isn't so much a functor-thing as a Haskell-thing. The reason it works is that functions are functors. Both `<$>` operators work in different functors!

`f <$> g` is in fact *the same* as `f . g`, so the equivalence you're asking about is rather more trivial than `f <$> (g <$> x) ≡ f . g <$> x`.

Comment: Thanks for this smart observation!

Comment: Well, I meant bringing the other Functor instance into consideration. Perhaps, "observation" is not a good word for this.

Comment: Moral of the story: (<$>) = (.) for the function Functor.

Comment: The `(<$>)` function for the function functor composes a function before a function which functions as the functor, whose `Functor` instance has the `(<$>)` function defined as the `(.)` function, whose function is to take a function and yield a function which takes a function and gives a function that functions like both functions composed together.

Comment: The same explanation for a code that mysteriously type-checks (not sure whether that code is additionally wrong or still equivalent to what was intended): [`forever putStrLn "Hello, infinity"`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9753389/94687)