# Understanding forever in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

Goal: take a string and print same thing in console like that same action need to be done forever

I came up something like this, no compilation error but not working as expected.

```
greet_buggy :: String -> IO ()
greet_buggy = forever $ putStrLn
```

Problem is below string is not printing anything in the console.

```
greet_buggy "something"
```

based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042977/how-does-forever-monad-work) I tried to debug and changed the definition like below. It is working fine

```
greet :: IO ()
greet = forever $ putStrLn "Hello"
```

Can anyone explain whats going on here? Is it possible to achieve same effect using `forever` alone?

EDIT: found one more related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753389/why-does-importing-control-applicative-allow-this-bad-code-to-type-check)(Thanks to @Daniel Wagner), even through this question is different from mine, answer explains about `forever`.

Comment: try `greet_buggy = forever . putStrLn`

Comment: thanks, working like greet, but still it is not complete solution to my Goal? I want to accept string and print it and accept one more string like that forever

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`greet_buggy` is working over a different monad.

`forever` takes a monadic action and repeats it indefinitely. It can be defined like this:

```
forever a = let loop = a >> loop in loop
```

which can also be visualized as

```
forever a = a >> a >> a >> a >> ...  (infinitely many times)
```

(In fact forever is defined over Applicative, not Monad; but this is not important right now).

So `forever greet` is actually

```
putStrLn "Hello" >> putStrLn "Hello" >> putStrLn "Hello" >> ...
```

which needs no further explanation.

OTOH `forever greet_buggy` is equivalent to

```
putStrLn >> putStrLn >> putStrLn >> ...
```

Now, since `(-> a)` is a monad, `>>` is defined for any two functions of suitable types, and the meaning of `f >> g` in this case is... just `g`! So the meaning of

```
( putStrLn >> putStrLn >> putStrLn >> ... ) "Hello"
```

is to take the last function in the chain of `>>` and apply it to `Hello`. Of course there's no last function there, so this just keeps running forever.

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone explain whats going on here?

We have

```
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

which, incidentally, is a value in the `(->) String` monad. Consequently,

```
forever putStrLn :: (->) String b
```

where `b` is universally quantified, hence we also have (unfortunately)

```
forever putStrLn :: (->) String (IO ())
```

making the posted code to type check.

To understand what is `forever` in the `(->) String` monad, recall that:

```
m >>= g
=  -- definition of >>=
\x -> g (m x) x
```

hence

```
m >> f
= -- definition of >> in terms of >>=
m >>= const f
= -- definition of >>=
\x -> const f (m x) x
= -- beta
\x -> f x
= -- eta
f
```

Back to `forever`: recall its definition

```
forever m = m >> forever m
```

which is equivalent (in the `(->) String` monad) to the recursive definition

```
forever m = forever m
```

causing a useless infinite loop.

Comment: so `forever $ putStrLn "something"` will always print same IO action i.e. printing something, in case I want to change "something" to "anything" in between can I do that using `forever`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: you might be looking for something like `forever (do s <- getLine ; putStrLn s)`

Comment: yes, your explanation and this comment solves my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`forever` performs the exact same IO action (or in general, monadic action) over and over. If your function accepts a String as input, `forever` will print that same string forever. If, instead, you want to read a string from the user each time, you must include that in your IO action.

What is a simple IO action that reads a line from the user and then prints it? Combine together `getLine` and `putStrLn`:

```
echo :: IO ()
echo = getLine >>= putStrLn
```

Then just pass that action to `forever`:

```
cat :: IO ()
cat = forever echo
```

Alternatively, it turns out there is already something built into Prelude that does this whole thing for you: what we've written is equivalent to:

```
cat :: IO ()
cat = interact id
```